# Google charts getting custom tooltips to work with an animation

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Well this is my code, it's broken.  I want to have absolute figures appear on mouse over, instead of percentages.  Google's guides do not have an example of this with an animation, their examples use data table methods rather than arrays.  I think I need to somehow tell Google that I have a third column which is a tooltip, at present it draws it as a bar.

```
     google.load("visualization", "1", {
   packages: ["corechart"]
 });
 google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

 function init() {
   var rowData1 = [
     ['key', 'Percentage', 'tooltip'],
     ['PLUS', 20.9, 3855],
     ['EDU', 18.4, 3400],
     ['GEO', 15.6, 2872],
     ['NO FLAG', 45.2, 8342]
   ];
   var rowData2 = [
     ['key', 'Percentage', 'tooltip'],
     ['PLUS', 54.2, 974],
     ['EDU', 6.7, 120],
     ['GEO', 39.2, 704],
     ['NO FLAG', 0.0, 0]
   ];

   // Create and populate the data tables.
   var data = [];
   data[0] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData1);
   data[1] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData2);

   var options = {
     // removes the key
     legend: {
       position: 'none'
     },
     // puts popup boxes on bar

     width: 600,
     height: 300,
     vAxis: {
       title: "vertical axis"
     },
     hAxis: {
       title: "horizontal axis"
     },
     seriesType: "bars",
     series: {
       5: {
         type: "line"
       }
     },
     animation: {
       duration: 1000,
       easing: 'out'
     },
   };
   var current = 0;
   // Create and draw the visualization.

   var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
   var button = document.getElementById('b1');

   function drawChart() {
     // Disabling the button while the chart is drawing.
     button.disabled = true;
     google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
       function() {
         button.disabled = false;
         button.value = 'Switch to ' + (current ? 'Tea' : 'Coffee');
       });
     options['title'] = 'Monthly ' + (current ? 'Coffee' : 'Tea') + ' Production by Country';
     // custom popup box request

     chart.draw(data[current], options);
   }
   drawChart();

   button.onclick = function() {
     current = 1 - current;
     drawChart();
   }
 }
```

I've tried converting the array data to DataTables and using

```
     if (current == 0) { chart.draw(dataTable1, options); }
     else{ chart.draw(dataTable2, options); }
```

To select which chart to draw, but this isn't working.  And it's less intelligible and inelegant, the dataTables need lots of properties set, so repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to define tooltip column with object notation...

```
var rowData1 = [
  ['key', 'Percentage', {role: 'tooltip'}],
  ['PLUS', 20.9, 3855],
  ['EDU', 18.4, 3400],
  ['GEO', 15.6, 2872],
  ['NO FLAG', 45.2, 8342]
];
var rowData2 = [
  ['key', 'Percentage', {role: 'tooltip'}],
  ['PLUS', 54.2, 974],
  ['EDU', 6.7, 120],
  ['GEO', 39.2, 704],
  ['NO FLAG', 0.0, 0]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change google visualization Combo Chart series option as below:

```
series: {
       0: {
         type: "line"
       }
    }
```

Every data table column is considered as one series in google visualization Combo Chart.

Here

**"Percentage"** is line series no is 0

**"tooltip"** is bar series no is 1

*Nothing wrong with google visualization Combo Chart.*

After above change you will get below output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well did want a bar chart, just hacking round with code example and that hung on in.  I changed it to type:'bar'

Comment: Well actually in your example both Percentage & tooltip series bind with single y axis & as tooltip series values are far greater than Percentage series values. So that when series type change to "bar" it will not appear on chart. Solution for this kind of problem will be use two axis to bind two different series like left y axis for tooltip & right y axis for Percentage. This kind of chart are called as multi axis Combo Chart. I hope you understand my points.